# Unable to connect to WIFI

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm new to Raspberry Pi usage and have taken over a Raspberry Pi project from a colleague who has just left. The model I'm using is 3B on a 7" Touch Display. Upon booting it up, it says `no wireless LAN interfaces found and eth0: Link is down`. I don't have a desktop to connect via ethernet. Also, when I go to configuration settings -> Localisation, the option to 'Set WLAN Country' is disabled.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you create a new SD card do they work? Do you know what version (and what O/S) you are running?

Comment: Gut feel if bits are removed backup SD card, start a new O/S, then migrate project files - who knows what your colleague has left (obviously no handover notes).

Comment: The "eth0: Link is down" is because you don't have a network cable connected. And I agree with previous comment, start fresh, never know what is left behind.

Comment: `sudo launchctl kickstart -k system/com.apple.airportd`

Answer (score 0):

You can download the newest Images of Raspberry Pi OS over [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/).
Make sure you choose the right one, which contains a Desktop environment for your touch display.

Reinstall the OS on your SD-Card by using `balenaEtcher` for example.

Follow this [manual](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md) to set up the wireless network without using a `ssh` connection or your `touch display`.